# How do you enable multi-touch for lubuntu 12.04 on my HP MINI trackpad?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, hp, multi-touch, trackpad

I have an HP MINI 110 with a multi touch trackpad. I have lubuntu 12.04 installed. I can't right click to save my life.

Comment: It's currently acting like a standard touchpad. There should be something I can put into the xorg.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using HP Mini 210, but I think we are using a same touchpad device. So here's three ways to do a right click:

1. Tap two fingers (do a multi-touch).
2. Tap the very bottom right of the pad instead of clicking it.
3. Place three fingers on the pad, then click it.